# How to display only one reference for equation using \align?

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

Good morning. I would like to understand how to write this equation and receive only one reference (example: equation 1.1) and not euqation 1.1 and 1.2 relative to the second line of the equation. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Figures/} }

\usepackage[%
style=apa, backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{float,lipsum,subfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox,tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools,array,dcolumn,longtable}
\usepackage[justification = centering]{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}    
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{align} 
\text{from}\quad r_i\geq20;\quad i= p+q \quad\text{where}\quad 
p= count[r_{j(i)}=0]\\ 
q=count[r_{j(i)}>10] 
\label{eq:eqr}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Another approach is to use equation and alignat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest `split`:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:eqr}
\begin{split}
\text{from}\quad r_i\geq20;\quad i= p+q \quad\text{where}\quad 
p &= \operatorname{count}[r_{j(i)}=0]\\ 
q &= \operatorname{count}[r_{j(i)}>10] 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also vertically center the two conditions, but in this case a brace seems needed.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:eqr}
\text{from}\quad r_i\geq20;\quad i= p+q \quad\text{where}\quad
\left\{\begin{aligned}
p &= \operatorname{count}[r_{j(i)}=0]\\ 
q &= \operatorname{count}[r_{j(i)}>10]
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: perfect! and what about placing p and q a bit upper?

Comment: @Elisam For my humble opinion is perfect.

Comment: @Elisam I added a possible alternative version; I'd avoid omitting the brace.

Comment: @Sebastiano thank you!

Comment: @egreg really thanks, i will consider both versions